# Inverted colors in Iphone

Tags: iphone, color, accessibility

Recently the colors on my Iphone 3g have started looking inverted or negative, I havent dropped my phone or had it damaged, but I cant seem to make it go back to normal.  i have also done some research on this and found out that you can purposely do this through accessibility but my phone doesnt give me that option....HELP!

Answer (score 3):

You need to look in General Settings. Scroll down to Accessibility. In there, you have a switch to turn White on Black on/off. That's the thing that reverses the colours on the iPhone.

Is your iPhone jailbroken?